# Apache ISIS libraries can't be integrated with dynamic-webProject?

Tags: java, isis

From document it seems like the projects stands apart from normal WebApps.
Excellent features, but isn't available as a light library to plug in with a Dynamic WebApp Java?

Answer (score 2):

No, an Apache Isis app can be built as a webapp (WAR) file.

For convenience we also provide a launcher - org.apache.isis.WebServer - that uses jetty to run the app from the command line.

Alternatively you could run from the mvn command line, using mvn jetty:run.

Comment: Dan, is it possible to get persistence decoupled out from DataNucleus, which is the core framework associated ..!? or can we choose DB which we prefer to persist ?

Comment: or can we choose DB which we prefer to persist over some other persistence mechanism rather DataNucleus ? Such as MetaModel..

Comment: Currently Apache Isis is tightly coupled to DN, at least for entities.  In principle you could build an app with no entities, just view models, and then roll your own persistence.  But it would be a lot of work.  DN supports many different persistence stores - not just RDBMS - and if you want to use some other persistence store then you could always implement DN's StoreManager SPI, see http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/extensions/store_manager.html.

Comment: can you please help me with ViewModel(just). Any examples would be perfect to start wit, cz all my previous work has no relation with DN. If I try to build everything up with DN.. Will be an equivalent time in comparison with learning wiring up the viewModel.

Comment: We have annotations source exposed, can we try to customise as we wanted?

Comment: Please ask these questions on the Apache Isis mailing list, thanks